# I want to upload image in codeigniter but my code does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

**view/image.php:**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
    <h3>Image Upload Form</h3>
    <input type="file" name="pic" tabindex="2" required>
   <input type="text" name="alt" placeholder="Image Alt Text" tabindex="1" 
   required>
  <button type="submit" id="img-submit" data-
   submit="Sending">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

**controller/upload.php:**

```
     public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
   $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  }
  function image()
 {
 $this->load->view('pages/image');
  }
 function upload()
    {
  $data = array(
    'image_url' => $this->input->$_FILES['pic']['name'],
    'alt' => $this->input->post('alt')
    )

   }
```

**models/upload_m.php:**

```
 <?php
 class pages_m extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
function upload($data)
{ 
return $this->db->insert('image',$data);

 }
}
?>
```

When I try to access the page through `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/image` it shows `error 404 not found`. Also would be grateful if someone could check my code for possible mistakes I might have made? Thanks in advance!

Comment: add multipart into form attribute

Comment: @AnandPandey as i am new to codeigniter i dont know much about this

Comment: Sorry the internet connection not worked. <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: is your problem solved or not?

Comment: @AnandPandey now just having issue with my uploading image no error but image is also not upload

Comment: Try my code and if you face any problem than plz comment

Comment: thanx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do should be correcting your form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then you should wrap  your controller code in this and take care at typo because this things are case sensitive

> (rename your controller using upper case for first letter:
>   Upload.php):

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

}
```

Then let's move to your model `(Pages_Model.php):`

```
class Page_Model extends CI_Model {

}
```

Also I do not see where you load your model in controller. You have to do something like this either in your controller's constructor or in the function you need to use model's functions:

```
$this->load->model('Page_Model');
```

And when you want to use the function from model you have to do it like this:

```
$this->Page_Model->function_name($data);
```

And you can always check codeigniter's website for documentation. It's very well written and easy to understand. Cheers!

LE: I forgot about upload.

```
 public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
```

Usefull link: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

This is an example function. In your code you didn't upload something. Your database can't keep files. You use it for filenames (in this case).

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

i think you forgot to write enctype in form tag.
use this code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Image Upload Form</h3>
    <input type="file" name="pic" tabindex="2" required>
   <input type="text" name="alt" placeholder="Image Alt Text" tabindex="1" 
   required>
  <button type="submit" id="img-submit" data-
   submit="Sending">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. form attrtibute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is missing which is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control. For more details https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp. You can also use CI helper funtion for declaring form tag `form_open_multipart`
2. The form action URL not correct which why you are getting 404 error. For more details https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html
3. You didn't include CI upload libraries and didn't follow basic steps mentioned in CI tutorial. Please find upload tutorial here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Welcome for any queries.

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/image.php';     i add this route in my route.php but still not working

Comment: @ranaaqibJaveed : Its not like that. You have to go through codeigniter documentation. Take a look at MVC. In routes, you have to mention the controller_name and function_name, not view path.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add this function in your controller and try.

```
  public function doupload()
     {
        $upload_path="https://localhost/project/profile"  
        $uid='10'; //creare seperate folder for each user 
        $upPath=upload_path."/".$uid;
        if(!file_exists($upPath)) 
        {
                   mkdir($upPath, 0777, true);
        }
        $config = array(
        'upload_path' => $upPath,
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", 
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('pic'))
        { 
            $data['imageError'] =  $this->upload->display_errors();

        }
        else
        {
            $imageDetailArray = $this->upload->data();
            $image =  $imageDetailArray['file_name'];
        }

     }
```

Comment: i tried your code but not working image is not going to db